# splash activity instead of white screen

Tags: android, layout, splash-screen

In the startup of my app, I have a white screen about two seconds. After I searched for it I figured out that that's because of heavy layouts. I want to know if it's possible to replace that white screen with a custom splash screen.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use a splash screen because you wants the user to see something while it's being loaded, you should reconsider and use theming instead. So instead of seeing a splash image that the user probably don't care about, show them a frame that closely resembles what they would see in the actual app (which is what Apple does for its iOS apps and Google does for its Android apps).

See [this article](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/) for an argument why splash screen is bad.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the best approach was to create a style like below:

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and set it to my MainActivity in manifest. The only problem is you should change the background drawable of your activity again with a white screen or whatever because window background gonna remain splash drawable. So at the end of onCreate() add this line:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.white);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to create a Layout for your "custom splash" and setting it up as the layout loaded when your application start, inflate the main/heavy layout in background (AsyncTask maybe ??) and when the inflation is done, change the splash screen for the new inflated one.

I'm not sure that would be a good solution so I won't give you any code to do so.. But if turns out that nobody come up with better and you want me to, I could try to make some kind of a solution if you need.

Comment: Hmm, It may ot be the better solution, but it should definitly be working.. Can you show me the code where you tried ?